# Data Annotations using Regular Expression fails on client side

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

The regular expression below allows characters (from different locales) and apostrophes, dashes, and  periods.

```
string test = "Abcede";
string test1 = "Abc2ede";
string test2 = "Abce$de";
string test3 = "Ab-e2de";
string test4 = "A'bcede";
string test5 = "A.bcede";
string test6 = "A_bcede";
string test7 = "A4bcede";
string test8 = "A'bcede";
string test9 = "sùéâàûù";

List<string> set = new List<string>()
{
    test,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8,test9
};

foreach (string s in set)
{
   bool blnValid = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[\p{L}'-.]+$");
}
```

When I try to use it as a data annotation in MVC it causes any input that passes in the above code to fail.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\p{L}'-.]+$", ErrorMessage = "ErrorMessage_InvalidCharactersLastNameField")] 
public override string LastName { get; set; }
```

How do I get model validation to work with a regex that allows characters (from different locales) and apostrophes, dashes, and  periods?

Comment: Try placing the hyphen at the end of the class. `@"^[\p{L}'.-]+$"`

Comment: No change.  Validation still fails client side.  I think there is differences between regex in .net and how the client side libraries (jquery.validate) interpret the expression.